# C++ Getting private value with getter

Tags: c++, getter, private-members

I have a class with private and public members I am trying to use a getter Get_Words() to access the private word member. This all compiles but when the value from `dir[NORTH].Get_Words() = "NORTH";` Whenever the word was just a public function without the Get_Words() member function using `dir[NORTh].word = "NORTH";`
Why isn't the Get_Words assigning the value correctly to word?

```
class Words
{
  public:
    static void Set_Words();
    string Get_Words();
  private:
    string word;
}

string Word::Get_Words()
{
  return word;
}

...
dir[NORTH].Get_Word() = "NORTH";
```

and I also tried

```
dir[NORTH].Get_Word() = Set_Word( string "North");
```

I'm pretty sure I did the setter wrong but I am new to object oriented programming in c++ and can't figure out the best way to do this.

Comment: because you need to make a public setter method as well...a getter method can only get not set

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add that I have also tried a setter method but could't implement it right. I'll update with the setter code tried also.

Comment: i noticed you declared `Get_Words` but called `Get_Word`...do you want it to be word or words? if words you should look into using arrays to manage multiple words

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::string Get_Word()` returns by value, aka it makes a copy of the word and returns it. When you try to assign to it, you are trying to assign to a right hand reference, which is impossible.

A way around this would to return a reference to word:

```
std::string& Get_Word();
```

But that is generally considered bad practice as the reference can outlive the class. A better way is to provide a setter along side the getter:

```
 void Set_Word(const std::string& w) {word=w;}
```

or even better:

```
 template <typename T>
 void Set_Word(T&& w) {word=std::foreward<T>(w);}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a private value, usually a public get function is implemented.

You want to set the value - usually a public set function is implemented for this task:

```
void Set_Word(string& newValue) { ... }
```

Or implement the Getter as returning a reference, as Vlad from Moscow stated.